How do I lay spc laminate in the opposite direction?
I'm laying down spc laminate, I started with one room and I'm proceeding in the directions for it to click. The problem will be to move sideways and the in the opposite direction of the click to cover rooms and spaces that the lateral moves won't reach. I could use a transition item in each door to isolate the rooms and as such I could lay down always in the correct direction. The downsides are:
Use of transitions
Possibile visual misalignment of the planks
So is there a way to move in the opposite direction of the click without transitions? Or is it suggested to have them anyway for possible material expansion? Thanks
Adding a picture,

I started from room K in that direction, room T will be easy to continue, then I will move sideways, still ok, to get to room S. But then from the point where I arrive in S to the wall between S and C and, even worse, C? I am not sure it will be easy going the opposite direction of the click, I need to try but I wanted also some suggestions first. I could start from the furthest wall of C, more or less, and try to meet the edge of S but that requires millimetric precision.
Multiple people suggested not to put transition items if possible, so basically it will be a single piece.

Usually if you change direction, it is a full 90 degrees, so a transom is the easiest.  Some do run the direction room to room, but it takes more measurement prep since most houses are not perfectly square.

@crip659 sorry, I was ambiguous, I don't mean to change direction of the planks, but they have a side where you click in and one to be clicked on. So there is a proper direction how to lay down rows, but I might have to go the opposite direction to cover a room and some  space

If done right from the beginning, then switching them around should be needed.  A very good/master cut would be needed, to not need a transom.  Usually you run from one room to the next with the same flooring, or do one room with one plank design and maybe do the next room with a different design/direction with a transom between.

Heck, laminate can shift too, so even a very good cut could end up gapping without a transition. @crip659 what are we talking about here with "transom?"  The transom I'm familiar with is above a door.

@Huesmann  Brain turned off for a bit.

Looking at the diagram. do the arrows represent the long side of the planks?  What is RIP?  Your diagram is confusing. are all lines walls?  if so how does one get from room K to rooms S and C?  If there are no walls please remove the lines.

@RMDman The lines are the walls, yes, there was a missing opening. The RIP is a small room which won't be covered with laminate anyway.
The arrows represent the direction I have to lay down the planks, the are orthogonal to the arrow. Basically is the click direction. For room C I put both directions because that is the room which is the main problem

Correct answers to your questions are dependant on the flooring and can vary slightly depending on manufacturer. For example, each manufacturer has a maximum distance of a run when a break or transition is needed.
How to proceed when faced with a situation of having to lay the the planks against the "click direction" is dependant on the room, the house and the overall plan.
I have installed many feet of this type of flooring in homes with a lower level footprint of about 1000 sq' and rarely needed transitions. This is because a plan was done, ( sometimes mentally) to allow the largest area to be covered first always running the flooring parallel to the longest wall. I also try to have any cuts needed in a doorway to be split between 2 planks rather than out of 1. Again this can be easy or difficult depending on the flooring. Usually when using this plan I rarely have to try to lay planks reverse of the "click direction". However if I do, it can be done with patience and a little skill.
In the sketch the yellow is where you should have started.
The red and blue arrows represents the "click direction" or the direction of progressive rows.
When entering into room S the direction of progression should be the same for both room S and C.


I will add a plan ASAP. As extra note I also shift every row by 1/3 of the length. I will check the instruction for max length

Done, I hope it is a bit clearer :)

The instructions said to lay them down following the direction where the light comes in, so the yellow plank I have it rotated 90° compare to your example

That's your problem.  You started laying the floor 90deg, wrong way.  I have been doing these floors for almost 2 decades and never ran the flooring according to how the light entered the room.   Without any intent of disrespect,  that sounds like a manufacturer that has an inferior product that shows waves when seen in the right light.

A good SPC will have a thickness of minimum 5.5mm.  What is the thickness of your flooring?

But the problem doesn't change, in the situation that you described, how would I go to U? It is the direction opposite to the click

The spc is 4mm thick. Maybe I misunderstood the instructions, but I think I will continue in that direction, it is not an option to remove it

I'm afraid you created a difficult situation by laying the flooring as you did.  In the best of situations you sometimes need to go opposite the "click"

I think it changes little, meaning that if I find a solution with your plan for room U, then I can apply it even to my layout. Basically how to go backwards

True, however my layout requires less going backwards.

But how do I go backwards? That's the main question. Is it possible?

Yes it is possible. It takes longer.  I can't tell you how to do it here in printed words, but it can be done.
